# Mutex in c++ is not running properly

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I am trying to use mutex to arrange the output between two threads to print the message from Thread 1 then print output from thread 2.
but I am getting the messages to be printed randomly so it seems like I am not using mutex correctly.

```
std::mutex mu;

void share_print(string msg, int id)
{
    mu.lock();
    cout << msg << id << endl;
    mu.unlock();
}

void func1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i > -50; i--)
    {
        share_print(string("From Func 1: "), i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(func1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        share_print(string("From Main: "), i);
    }

    t1.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:
[image]

Comment: The output is as expected. There's nothing in your code that would 'interleave' the printouts from main and from the thread.

Comment: *"to print the message from Thread 1 then print output from thread 2."* -- did you mean this as an example? There's nothing in your code that tells thread 2 to wait until thread 1 reaches the mutex before proceeding. Even if the mutex could prevent interleaving, thread 2 grabbing the mutex before thread 1 would still be a possibility.

Comment: The output is as expected.   Your usage of the mutex in `share_print()` ensures every individual line is output completely, with no interruption in the middle of a line.   However, there is nothing preventing the loops in `main()` and `func1()` from being interleaved.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of mutexes is 100% correct. It's your expectation of mutex behavior, and execution thread behavior, that misses the mark. For example, C++ execution threads give you no guarantees whatsoever that any line in `func1` will be executed before `main()` completely finishes executing its `for` loop.

As far as mutexes are concerned, your only guarantees, that matter here are:

1. Only one execution thread can lock a given `std::mutex` at the same time.
2. If a `std::mutex` is not locked, one of two things will happen when an execution thread attempts to lock it, either: a) it will lock it b) if another thread already has it locked or manages to lock it first it will block until the mutex is no longer locked, and then it will attempt to lock the mutex again.

It is very important to understand all the implications of these rules. Even if your execution thread has a mutex locked, then proceeds to unlock it, and then lock it again, it may end up re-locking the mutex immediately even if another execution thread is also waiting to lock the mutex. Mutexes do not impose any kind of a queueing, a locking order, or a priority between different execution threads that are trying to lock it. It's a free-for-all.

Even if mutexes worked the way you expected them to work, that still gives you no guarantees whatsoever:

```
std::thread t1 (func1 );
```

Your only guarantee here is that `func1` will be called by a new execution thread at some point on ***or after*** this `std::thread` object's construction finishes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    share_print(string("From Main: "), i);
}
```

This entire `for` loop can finish even before a single line from `func1` gets executed. It'll lock and unlock the mutex 50 times and call it a day, before func1 wakes up and does the same.

Or, alternatively, it's possible for `func1` to run to completion before `main` enters the `for` loop.

You have no expectations of any order of execution of multiple execution threads, unless ***explicit syncronization*** takes place.

In order to achieve your interleaving output a lot more work is needed. In addition to just a mutex there will need to be some kind of a condition variable, and a separate variable that indicates whose "turn" it is. Each execution thread, both `main` and `func1`, will not only need to lock the mutex, but block on the condition variable until the shared variable indicates that it's turn is up, then do its printing, set the shared variable to indicate that it's the other thread's turn, signal the condition variable, and only then unlock the mutex (or, always keep the mutex locked and always spin on the condition variable).